# how to handle extra parameters on the swift model class

Tags: swift, codable

I am new to swift. I create a codable model class and when the back end team added extra parameters on it my model class is not supporting. Can someone please explain how to achieve this.

```
 public struct Posts : Codable {
        let`internal` : Bool?
        let documents : [Document]?
        let entityID : String?
      enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case `internal` = "internal"
            case documents = "documents"
            case entityID = "entityID"
}
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            `internal` = try (values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .internal) ?? false)
            documents = try values.decodeIfPresent([Document].self, forKey: .documents)
            entityID = try (values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .entityID) ?? "")
} }
```

My codable look like this anything goes wrong on this.

Comment: What is your question, exactly what is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic stuct I've given without a custom `init(decoder:)` method, and it would still work even if new parameters are added later on. You can add them as you require them.

```swift
public struct Posts: Codable {
    let`internal`: Bool?
    let documents: [Document]?
    let entityID: String?
}
```

Note: You need to add new keys to the `struct` manually if you want to access them. This struct only gives what's already been parsed by the `struct`. This won't break unless the backend decides to provide a different value type for one of these keys. If new keys are added that you would like to access modify the `struct` to this:

```swift
public struct Posts: Codable {
    let`internal`: Bool?
    let documents: [Document]?
    let entityID: String?
    let newPropertyName: NewPropertyType
}
```

Comment: Yes. Coding keys are only required if you have changes in the rawValue of the property name given in the `struct`.

Comment: Note that to get the new keys that have been added you need to add them to this struct. But this won't break.

Comment: Is there any way that we can Append newly added keys dynamically. without adding in struct in ios

Comment: My problem is I have an existing model class like above .back end team is keep on changing the reasons like they are adding extra parameters  and changing the existing key names so when I am converting data to model .it failing always what may be the issue is it issue with changing the key name or adding the extra parameters .please help me on this

Comment: Changing the keys in the API response as and when required is not an option and cannot be handled by the front end other than show the end user that something has gone wrong. I think you should approach the back-end team to create and maintain a model for the API's you require and instead of making breaking changes to the model append new changes to it.